# Azure data factory not deleting a linked service when merging branches using Azure devops CI CD pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, cicd, linked-service

I have a linked service to a blob storage account in my ADF and what I'm finding is that when I delete the linked service from  my azure datafactory (that is linked to my dev branch), that change is not getting picked up as file change when I merge my dev branch into my test branch (which still has the linked service).

I can see my commit under the commits tab on the merge window, so devops knows I've made a change, but the files tab doesn't show the linked service being removed.

Has anyone experienced this issue? and is there a way around it?

Further information:

Screenshots

Screenshot 1 showing the release branch with the linked service that we want to delete.

[image]

Screenshot 2 showing the dev branch with the linked service removed

[image]

Screenshots below showing the details of the pull request in azure devops,

Screenshot 3 shows the dev branch linked services folder (note the linked service that we dont want has been removed)

[image]

Screenshot 4 shows the release branch that still has the linked service that we are hoping to remove.

[image]

Screenshot 5 shows the merge request that does not have the removal of the linked service under the list of files.

[image]

Screen 6 showing that the commit where we removed the linked service is included in the branch history.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Martin, checked on my side, if the `deleteme` linked service on `release` branch is ahead of `dev` branch, when pull request is created, it won't list it in the Files tab. You can find the details in the reply below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same pull request appearance with you, it could happen with below steps:

1. In your dev branch, you don't have `deleteme` linked service currently. then created `release` branch based on the `dev` branch.
2. Create `deleteme` linked service on `release` branch, which means release branch is `ahead` of dev now.
3. Delete `pipeline1.json` from `dev` branch, create pull request from dev to release branch.
4. On `dev` branch, create `deleteme` linked service, then delete it.

Pull request `files` tab:
[image]

Pull request `commit` tab:

[image]

In above, it was caused that the deleteme linked service on `release` branch is `ahead` of `dev` branch, when pull request is created, it won't list it in the Files tab.

Comment: Hi Wade, I am also struggling with this same issue. The way you are completing it would be right and i wouldn't expect to see the linked service in the file. The way you have tried this is by editing on the release branch which would never happen. All code changes go into dev and are merged into release. In this case - both dev and release have the linked service, linked service is deleted from dev, merge request from dev to release. The deleted linked service doesn't show as a change.

Comment: @AdamWilson, the step above is a sample, the point is the release branch is ahead of dev branch when creating PR then the appearance could happen. If you still have the error, may i know how you remove the linked service from `dev` branch? Please try to remove from web UI not local machine for a check.